# SQL Server Query representations of equi join

Tags: sql-server, sql

Are these queries both representations of equi join?

I find that both returns the same result.

Query1:

```
SELECT C.* FROM [Case] A, [Event] B, Notice C
WHERE A.CaseID = B.CaseID
AND B.EventID = C.EventID
```

Query2:

```
SELECT C.* FROM [Case] A
join [Event] B on A.CaseID = B.CaseID
join Notice C on B.EventID = C.EventID
```

Please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, same queries, different syntax.

The second query is better written as:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM [Case] A 
inner join [Event] B on A.CaseID = B.CaseID 
inner join Notice C on B.EventID = C.EventID
```

The second query using ANSI syntax has some advantages over the first:

- easy to see when you have a missing `ON` clause
- makes it clear what *kind* of join is being done
- separates `JOIN` clause from `WHERE` clause

Comment: PLus of course it is the more recent syntax, the other is 18 years out of date for reasons you explained above. 

It is also easier to mainatain especially when needing to add left joins as the old-style syntax does not have good support for left joins (In SQL Server at least). In fact they are deprecated and right now in SQL server that they may return incorrect results as the optimized gets confused as to whether it is a left join or a cross join.

Comment: Good points - plus I have a **strong aversion** to the pre-ANSI syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

When using the comma in the FROM clause, it's the same as the keyword JOIN. Usually, you'd be using INNER JOIN or a form of OUTER JOIN which gives much more efficient results.